# Add YEAR from a date field in classic email template

Tags: email-template

I have a date field that I am trying to pull the year out of it and concatenate it with other text. I was thinking it should work in the HTML Classic Email template since I can get this to work End Date: 12/31/**{!right(Today,4)}**

But when I try to change the field from Today to my field it does not work. I am currently trying this.

DMU End Date: **{!right(text(Custom_Solution__c.Contracted_End_Date__c,4))}** but that is not working for me.

Thanks

Comment: You might try `{!right(text(RelatedTo.Contracted_End_Date__c,4))}`, but I'm not sure even that is supported in Classic templates (I'd recommend using Visualforce, instead).

Comment: Or ensure you have a formula field to hold the value you need. That said, this is likely to cause issues around timezones due to lack of timezone support in formulas.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I tried that updated code and it did not work. My SF admin said he did not think it would work either. Thanks for the extra help.